# 'require' is not defined - Sveltekit with typescript

Tags: typescript, svelte, commonjs, sveltekit, ecma

I'm using both `import` and `require` syntax in `.ts` files in a Svelte project, and wondering why it's giving me the error

> require is not defined

I am wondering if there is a hole in my knowledge and am missing something simple?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "esnext"],
        "target": "es5",
        /**
            svelte-preprocess cannot figure out whether you have a value or a type, so tell TypeScript
            to enforce using \`import type\` instead of \`import\` for Types.
            */
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        /**
            To have warnings/errors of the Svelte compiler at the correct position,
            enable source maps by default.
            */
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "paths": {
            "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.svelte"]
}
```

sveltekit config:

```
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess'
import ssr from '@sveltejs/adapter-static'

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
export default {
  preprocess: [
    preprocess({
      defaults: {
        style: 'postcss'
      },
      postcss: true
    })
  ],

  kit: {
    adapter: ssr(),
    target: '#svelte'
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `require` with SvelteKit, only `import` is valid syntax.

Comment: Many popular libs actually still use it (like `axios` for instance) and building using vite/Sveltekit will create a script that throw `require is undefined` in the browser

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with how Typescript transpilation occurs during the Svelte build. It happened to me while using only "import" style imports and Svelte+Typescript. Typescript is probably transpiling an "import" into a "require()" due to some internal misconfiguration. It also only happens to some npm libraries/modules.

An accepted (though imperfect) answer from Svelte (not Typescript) Github on the same issue yields the advice of install the given dependency (for me it was dotenv) as a devDependency rather than a usual browser-side dep. It worked for me. The reason this happens is svelte and sveltekit necessarily include a few different build steps internally with vite and rollup. There is clearly something that didn't translate the import correctly, but it's not something that you as a front end svelte dev should have to worry about.

Hopefully they issue more guidance on this, but the general wisdom I've found with "require" related issues and Svelte is try it as a dev dependency.